# Ruby on Rails API Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am looking at creating a basic Rails application that can access this API http://instructure.github.io/ I have had a look through the documentation but cannot find anywhere I can get to grips with unfortunately. I am fairly new to Rails but I understand the basics. I was wondering if anyone knows of a good tutorial or resources where I can learn how to build a rails application that calls a third party API and displays the results. I know Canvas Instructure API is via JSON requests. Any information would be very much appreciated.

I would like to note that it uses Oauth2 for API authorisation for requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at [Httparty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) gem, It should do everything you need to consume an api

Here's an example of using [omniauth and Httparty](https://github.com/quintonwall/omniauth-rails3-forcedotcom/wiki/Build-Mobile-Apps-in-the-Cloud-with-Omniauth,-Httparty-and-Force.com) to connect to a 3rd party api

Answer (score 0):

YOu can also take a look at oauth-plugin - https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin - which gives you both OAuth Provider and Consumer. Implementing the consumer should give you what you need.